# Definir funções para valores iguais e valores em ordem crescente - Python

Tags: python, funções

Olá, defini uma função para leitura de 100 fichas de registros, contendo nome, sexo e idade, e agora necessito de uma função separada para mostrar na tela quantas pessoas são do sexo masculino e outra função separada para mostrar o vetor em ordem crescente de idade. Como poderia ser feito? Obrigado.

```
#Fazendo a ficha com nome sexo e idade
def leitura_registros():
    registros = []
    for x in range(100):
        fichaderegistros = {
        "Nome": input("Digite o nome: "),
        "Sexo": input("Digite o sexo: "),
        "Idade": int(input("Digite a idade: "))
        }
        registros.append(fichaderegistros)
    return registros


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Faz a leitura dos registros
    registros = leitura_registros()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para contar quantas são de um determinado sexo, a lógica é bem simples: percorrer a lista e quando encontrar um registro com o sexo desejado, adicionar um contador. Basicamente, ficaria assim:

```
def contar_por_sexo(registros, sexo):
    resultado = 0
    for registro in registros:
        if registro['Sexo'] == sexo:
            resultado += 1
    return resultado

qtd_homens = contar_por_sexo(registros, 'M')
print(f'Há {qtd_homens} na lista')
```

Já para ordenar por ordem crescente, basta utilizar a função nativa `sorted`:

```
def ordenar_por_idade(registros):
    return sorted(registros, key=lambda it: it['Idade'])
```

Comment: @JoãoMoreira basta percorrer a lista retornada por `ordenar_por_idade` e exibir com `print`. Deixo isso a seu cargo.

Answer (score 0):

Não testei, mas acredito que é bem simples e deve funcionar:

```
#Fazendo a ficha com nome sexo e idade
registros = []
masculinos = []
idadesCrescente = []

def leitura_registros():

for x in range(100):
    fichaderegistros = {
    "Nome": input("Digite o nome: "),
    "Sexo": input("Digite o sexo F ou M: "),
    "Idade": int(input("Digite a idade: "))
    }
    registros.append(fichaderegistros)
    return registros


if __name__ == '__main__':
# Faz a leitura dos registros
    registros = leitura_registros()


def sexoMasculino(registros):

    for i in registros:
        if i == "M" or i == "m":
            masculinos.append(i)

def idadesCrescente(){
    cont = 0   # cont serve como uma chave, 0 fechada e 1 aberta
    for a in registros:
    if cont != 0: #Quando cont for zero, não entra nesse if
            idadesCrescentes.append(a)
            cont = 0 #Após armazenar o valor a chave é fechada

    if a == "M" or a == "m":
            cont = 1 # se as condições acima forem verdadeiras, significa que o termo seguinte será o valor de idade e a chave será liberada para o próximo loop.

    return idadesCrescentes.sort()
    }
```

Considerações:
A função `sexoMasculino()` irá fazer uma varredura pelo vetor `registros` e verificará em qual posição encontra-se o valor `M`, `m`, `F` ou `f` e assim armazenar em outro vetor, logo será armazenado somente o valores de sexo.

Para a função `idadesCrescente()`, será verificada se o termo de sexo foi encontrado e se sim, sabemos que o valor seguinte será a idade, logo a chave é liberada e no loop seguinte o if de idade será true e armazenará a idade. Após a função .sort fará a organização em ordem crescente dos valores.

Agora é só chamar os métodos onde quiser e sem precisar passar nenhum parâmetro. Qualquer coisa avisa ai

Comment: Sua função de ordenar pela idade não pareceu fazer muito sentido. Poderia explicá-la?